# TypeError: authJwt is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I am doing an e-shop project using MERN stack in that I faced the above error

**app.js:**

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const morgan = require("morgan");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const cors = require("cors");

require("dotenv/config");

const authJwt = require('./helpers/jwt');

app.use(cors());

app.options("*", cors());

//middleware

app.use(express.json());

app.use(morgan("tiny"));

app.use(authJwt());

//Routes

const categoriesRoutes = require("./routes/categories");

const productsRoutes = require("./routes/products");

const usersRoutes = require("./routes/users");

const ordersRoutes = require("./routes/orders");



const api = process.env.API_URL;

app.use(`${api}/categories`, categoriesRoutes);

app.use(`${api}/products`, productsRoutes);

app.use(`${api}/users`, usersRoutes);

app.use(`${api}/orders`, ordersRoutes);



//Database

mongoose

  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING, {

    useNewUrlParser: true,

    useUnifiedTopology: true,

    dbName: "animal-feedmart-database",

  })

  .then(() => {

    console.log("Database Connection is ready...");
  })
  
.catch((err) => {
  
  console.log(err);
  
});


//Server

app.listen(3000, () => {

  console.log("server is running http://localhost:3000");
});
```

Near `app.use(authJwt())` it is showing error.

Can anyone help me to solve the error

Thanks in advance

Comment: please check the `require('./helpers/jwt')` path, and you should export `authJwt` function in `./helpers/jwt'` currectly

Answer (score 0):

// Auth JWToken
const {authJwt} = require('./helpers/jwt')

// Middleware
app.use(authJwt);

// JWT
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D2tD.png

Answer (score 0):

i try this modification and it works try and see the results

```js
const { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt")


function authJwt(){
    let secret = process.env.SEC_TOK;
    return jwt({
        secret,
        algorithms: ['HS256']
    })
}
module.exports = authJwt;
```